# Showing external drives

Tags: gnome, usb, mount

Have Ubuntu 20.04. Everything works fine. Except when I plug in a USB drive, nothing appears on the desktop nor is displayed on my favorites bar. However I see in Live Ubuntu any drive plugged in does appear on that bar.

There seems to be no easy way of configuring for this. Tweaks doesn't provide a means. The only 'quick' way I can tell that a drive is mounted in GUI is to open my Home folder, where a side bar is displayed showing (amongst other things) my mounted drive.

This seems to be a Gnome issue. If I use Cinnamon as a DM, all external drives are automatically displayed on the desktop when plugged in. With Gnome I use Tweaks with Dash To Panel and thought, if anywhere that would be the place for how to deal with the appearances of external drives. But there's nothing there in the various configurations for this.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-mounts true`
....Shows the mounts on the dock. (I don't believe gnome displays it via desktop)

Additionally, make sure your usb is actually mounted when you plug it in.... `gnome-disks` can easily show that.

....gnome-disks can also can easily edit the "Edit mount options"(which is essentially /etc/fstab) that affect the mounts displaying - ",x-gvfs-show" or even easier just checking the "show in user interface" box.

Comment: That gsettings command made no difference. Still have to open file manager to check if external drive is seen or mounted. I suppose I can open gnome-disks to check as well, but I'd rather just see an icon on the dock or desktop when I plug a drive in.

Comment: @PaulBenson but is it actually mounted? plugging them in and mounting are two different actions. Your usb may not be automounting... So if you plug it in, you may see it in gnome-disks unmounted.. while youre there, mount it with gnome-disks... I saw the same behavior until i started playing with the above mentioned options

Comment: Yes. It always mounts, but doesn't show it while I'm on the desktop. That's why I always have to open Files when using Gnome just to check.

Comment: @PaulBenson did you experiment with gnome-disks and its option to display it???? i was seeing some inconsistent behavior myself, when I was toying with that and comparing the results of `mount`.

Answer (score 0):

The gnome shell extension Desktop Icons NG (DING) can add mounted drives on the desktop and much more.
It is available on [https://extensions.gnome.org/](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2087/desktop-icons-ng-ding/)